# with ef 4.1 code first how can i create a nullable column

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework-4, ef-code-first, nullable, code-first

I have the following POCO:

```
Public Class T1

<Required()>
<MaxLength(128)>
<Key(), Column(Order:=0)>
Property K1 As String

<Required()>
<MaxLength(128)>
<Key(), Column(Order:=1)>
Property K2 As String

<Required()>
Property C1 As String

Property C2 As String

end Class
```

I would expect C2 to be created as Nullable, but both C1 and C2 are Not Null.  Adding

```
    <Required(AllowEmptyStrings:=True)>
```

Does not make a difference, as it seems the  decoration is aimed at data validation, not DB creation.

So how do i get a nullable column with Code First?

Comment: Following @Ladislav's help, i found the following syntax for the fluent API: modelBuilder.Entity(Of T1)().Property(Function(t) t.C1).IsOptional()

Comment: And the final touch - as @Ladislav points out, it is enough to declare C1 As Integer? to get a nullable column - no need for the fluent API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to say that `string` property is nullable by attributes because it is default behaviour if you don't mark property with `RequiredAttribute`. In case of fluent mapping you can describe it as:

```
context.Entity(Of T1)().Property(Function(t) t.C2).IsNullable(True)
```

Comment: Thanks.  As i state above, omitting the <Required()> attribute still results in a NOT Null column.  I will try your fluent API suggestion.

Comment: If I omit the required value (only difference is that I'm using C#) I get nullable column. Try delete your database and run the code again.

Comment: You are right - for strings.  I wasn't testing correctly but as you say - for strings Nullable is the default.  For other types - Integers at any rate, the fluent API is needed.  Ended up using a slightly different syntax as i don't see IsNullable as a member of Property.  The final code is in the remark to my question - thanks for your help.

Comment: If you want nullable `int` you must use `int?` and you don't need fluent api.

Comment: where is `context` comming from? I tried `OnModelCreating` where context on my class `MyContext` (derived from `DBContext`) but could not find `IsNullable`. Only `IsModified`