# Code First Migration Seed Error: The binary operator Equal is not defined for the types 'System.Nullable`1[System.Int32]' and 'System.Int32'

Tags: c#, entity-framework, code-first, entity-framework-migrations, seed

I have the following issue with my update identifiers when seeding to my db:

```
context.ClientPromos.AddOrUpdate(
            cp => new { cp.ClientID, cp.Recommendation_ID, cp.PromoCode_ID },

            new ClientPromo
            {
                ClientID = 0,
                Recommendation_ID = Rec30Off.RecommendationID,
                PromoCode_ID = pc30PerOffProd.PromoCodeID
            },
            new ClientPromo
            {
                ClientID = 0,
                Recommendation_ID = RecKnow.RecommendationID,
            },

            new ClientPromo
            {
                ClientID = 0,
                Recommendation_ID = RecCall.RecommendationID,
            },
);

context.SaveChanges();
```

Since `cp.Recommendation_ID` and `cp.PromoCode_ID` are `int? datatypes`, it gets the following error:

> The binary operator Equal is not defined for the types
>   'System.Nullable`1[System.Int32]' and 'System.Int32'.

I have viewed this article and added the `modelBuilder` - `IsOptional()` code described, but it doesn't work for me and I get the same error in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16818382/the-binary-operator-equal-is-not-defined-between-type-nullableint32-and-int32).

If I change:

```
cp => new { cp.ClientID, cp.Recommendation_ID, cp.PromoCode_ID }
```

To:

```
cp => new { cp.ClientID }
```

It works fine, however this will not work if I need to update a record it will just duplicate every record in the table.

Comment: did you solve your issue ? Maybe that will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16818382/the-binary-operator-equal-is-not-defined-between-type-nullableint32-and-int32

Answer (score 6):

There is an error in Entity Framework AddOrUpdate method. I created an issue in EF repository:

https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework6/issues/9

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure how much you're familiar with [Nullable Types (C# Programming Guide)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx) but the long story short as the name represents,

> A nullable type can represent the correct range of values for its
>   underlying value type, plus an additional null value.

You can allocate a normal type to a nullable type but NOT the other way around as when the value is `null` we will get into trouble so compiler which catch this error in the compile time.

However, there are easier ways to go around this issue if that's your only one and a simple if statement will sort everything out before the allocation.

```
var myIntVar = myIntVar_Nullable ?? default(int);
```

which is a syntactic sugar for

```
var myIntVar = myIntVar_Nullable == null ? default(int) : myIntVar_Nullable;
```

Comment: But this only happens when i am placing the columns to be identified for the addorupdate function for the code first migration. Not sure how i can apply this to that. If i remove those columns it works fine, but by doing that it continues to add rows to the db instead of updating them.

Comment: I'll look into it in more specifics then